# Change symbol types for point features on mapview in R

Tags: r, leaflet, mapview

Using the R mapview package, I'd like to use different symbol types/shapes, linked to a column in the table. e.g.

```
library(mapview)
library(sf)

head(breweries)
set.seed(999)
breweries$coop <- factor(replicate(nrow(breweries), sample(c("yes", "no"), 1, replace = T)))
table(breweries$coop)

mapview(breweries, zcol = "coop")
```

e.g. a functionality like this:

```
plot(breweries[,"founded"], pch = c(1,2)[breweries$coop])
```

Are there different symbols available for point features? If not, how can I use custom symbols but maintain a functionality that allows graduated colours, as in the default circles.